# How to backup and restore PostgreSQL programmatically without using pg_dump and psql?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I have a kubernetes space where the PostgreSQL DB is on a different POD than the executor where my Typescrtipt code is being executed, which means that I do not have access to pg_dump and psql. Is there a typescript npm library which can backup and restore the DB programmatically and remotely or a special client which I can install in project so that I can use? I could not find such an mpm library or client on the internet.

Another thing that I can think of is some "universal" SQL script, which makes the backup and another one for the restore, if there is such a thing at all.

Comment: `backup and restore the DB programmatically and remotely or a special client` pg_dump/pg_restore can be executed from a *remote* host, just like any other client program.

Comment: Yes, but I cannot have pg_dump/pg_restore on the remote host. Furthermore, when the project is run locally it is being run on Windows or MAC, while through Jenkins it is being run on Linux.